# Can I edit/remove autostart commands?

Tags: boot-issues, noobs, retropie

When I turn on my Raspberry Pi, I receive the following error message:

```
bash: /opt/retropie/configs/all/autostart.sh: No such file or directory
```

I had previously installed `RetroPie`, but have since run the uninstall function in the RetroPie’s setup file, but it doesn’t seem to have removed everything that it installed.

I can boot the desktop manually after this point using `startx`, but as a learning exercise I'd like to know how I can view the list of commands that the OS is trying to execute during the bootup sequence, with the aim to hopefully remove the part calling for `RetroPie` to be booted.

Is something like this possible? Grateful for any advice!

Comment: "I accidentally installed RetroPie" - HOW?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I hadn’t realised that RetroPie is designed to be installed onto a standalone, dedicated Raspberry Pi. It’s not designed to be launched within a desktop environment. I only realised my error after it was already installed, now I’m trying to reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to find out what was left behind by the uninstaller, you could do the following:

1. Install a fresh system
2. Make a backup
3. Install RetroPie
4. Uninstall RetroPie
5. Compare your current system with the backup from step 2.

Of course, if you have a backup of your system before you installed RetroPie, you can directly proceed to comparison.

Once you lean what needs to be undone, you can come back to your current installation and undo the damage manually. Searching for the leftover commands directly on your current system (with no backup to compare with) may take time, since they could be anywhere in

- SystemD configuration
- Xorg startup scripts or config files
- Autorun/config files of your desktop manager
- Autorun/config files of your window manager
- Many other places on your system such as udev rules, scripts in user folders, legacy SysV scripts, etc.